# Исключения С++ и критические секции

Tags: многопоточность, c++, исключения

Корректен ли код?

```
bool started_cs = false;  
try {  
    // ...  
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);  
    started_cs = true;  
    // ...  
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);  
    started_cs = false;  
} catch(SomeException&) {  
    if (started_cs)  
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);  
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: У нас с коллегой вышел спор, по поводу вашего вопроса.
Я считаю что при вопросе "Корректен ли код?" отвечать надо с точки зрения языка/компилятора. И тогда код корректен. 
Но коллега считает, что за токой код нужно лишать первичных половых признаков и еще куча непристойных вещей, а на последок рассказать о том, что существует RII. И попросить переделать с RII либо перестать увеличивать энтропию.


Comment: Ваш коллега плохо осведомлен - что ни делай, энтропия все равно увеличивается :) Google не очень помог с RII, и я нутром чую что "поллитра, но доказать не могу". Впрочем, я просто забыл про то, что такие задачи решаются классами под названием Guard.

Comment: Не RII, а RAII. Это когда время жизни некоего внешнего ресурса жёстко завязано на время жизни внутреннего объекта. Иными словами, некий простенький класс-обёртка хранит в себе идентификатор внешней сущности, уничтожая её в своём деструкторе. Николас, кстати, в своём ответе дал пример использования этой техники.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Код вполне корректен, но я бы посоветовал отказаться от переменных типа бул для синхронизации. Вы можете сделать, к примеру, так:

```
try {  
// ...  

    try {
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs); 
        // ...  
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs); 
    } catch(...) {  // Ловим все исключения...   
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);  
        throw;      // ...и пробрасываем их дальше.
    }
// ...  
} catch(SomeException&) {
    // ...
}
```

А вообще, лучше сделать умную критическую секцию. Создать объект, в конструкторе вызвать  `EnterCriticalSection(&cs)`, а в деструкторе `LeaveCriticalSection(&cs)`. Тогда при раскрутке стека критическая секция будет освобождена.

Comment: Спасибо! Точно, через объекты лучше всего.